# F-bounded type generic vs abstract type

Tags: scala, generics

I have a trait and a case class:

```
trait Foo[T <: Foo[T]] {
  def self: T
}

case class Bar() extends Foo[Bar] {
  def self = this
}
```

I would like to create a type that can take case classes that extend `Foo`. If I create a trait using generics:

```
trait TT[Key <: Foo[Key]] {
  def f(key: Key) = {
    key
  }
}

val tt = new TT[Foo[_]]{}
tt.f(Bar())
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to express the same thing using abstract types:

```
trait T {
  type Key <: Foo[Key]
  def f(key: Key) = {
    key
  }
}
val t = new T{}
t.f(Bar()) //doesn't compile
```

Why the second version doesn't work?

EDIT:

As @Jasper-M pointed out, the first version doesn't work either, here is the updated version that works:

```
import scala.language.existentials

trait Foo[+T <: Foo[T]] {
  def self: T
}

object Foo {
  type Any = Foo[T] forSome { type T <: Foo[T] }
}

val tt = new TT[Foo.Any]{}
tt.f(Bar())
```

Comment: Can I just ask why you would want to do that out of curiosity given the f bounded generic already gives you what's required?

Comment: Most of my code is using abstract types, I would need to rewrite all using generics if this is not possible.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using abstract types?

Comment: It's more convenient for my purposes, as the type is specified in the code at the bottom of the hierarchy and it's not exposed to the client as a parameter.

Comment: By the way, your "works fine" version doesn't compile for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the `Key` type to `Bar`.

```
scala> val t = new T { type Key = Bar }
t: T{type Key = Bar} = $anon$1@2c34c819

scala> t.f(Bar())
res0: t.Key = Bar()
```